# Initializing realm globally causing a crash

Tags: ios, swift, realm, appdelegate

I have a swift app with realm integrated to it. I am declaring the realm globally in the AppDelegate.swift as shown below in the code. When I execute this application, My app runs fine on the devices and even in the test mode.

Issue:

After my app submission, the Apple review board rejected app and the symbolicated crash logs pointed the initialisation of the realm.

Below is the code, what am I possibly doing wrong?

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Firebase
import UserNotifications
import Fabric

import RealmSwift

var uiRealm = try! Realm()

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
var tokenExists = false

let imageDb = DigitalFingerprint()
var uid: String!


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


    #if DEVELOPMENT
        print("Development Mode Started")
        let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info", ofType: "plist")
        guard let fileopts = FirebaseOptions.init(contentsOfFile: filePath!)
            else {
                fatalError("Couldn't load config file")
        }
        FirebaseApp.configure(options: fileopts)
    #else
        print("Production Mode Started")
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    #endif

    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        if (user != nil) {
            print("User is there")
            self.uid = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: KEY_UID)
        } else {
            print("user signed out")
            DB_URL.removeAllObservers()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "starts") as? BootVC
                var topRootViewController: UIViewController = (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController)!
                while((topRootViewController.presentedViewController) != nil){
                    topRootViewController = topRootViewController.presentedViewController!
                }
                topRootViewController.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    if uid != nil {
        checkforAccess()
    }

    return true
}
```

Following is the Real object, DigitalFingerprint.swift

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
import UIKit

class DigitalFingerprint: Object {

@objc dynamic var imageData: Data? = nil
@objc dynamic var fid : String? = nil
@objc dynamic var uid : String? = nil
override static func primaryKey() -> String {
    return "uid"
}

}

extension DigitalFingerprint {

func writeToRealm(){
    try! uiRealm.write {
        uiRealm.add(self, update: true)
    }
}

func DeleteFromRealm(object: Results<DigitalFingerprint>){
    try! uiRealm.write {
        uiRealm.delete(object)
    }
}

}
```

crash Logs received by apple review board. :

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001830142e8 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001831292f8 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 396
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000182f83060 __abort + 152
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000182f82fc8 __abort + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018271f068 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018271f1f8 default_terminate_handler+ 8696 () + 280
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000182748820 _objc_terminate+ 34848 () + 140
7   SpotMi                          0x0000000100dc7d78 CLSTerminateHandler() + 1260920 (CLSException.mm:314)
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018273754c std::__terminate(void (*)+ 107852 ()) + 16
9   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001827375b8 std::terminate+ 107960 () + 60
10  Realm                           0x0000000101f94a00 realm::Realm::open_with_config(realm::Realm::Config const&, std::__1::unique_ptr<realm::Replication, std::__1::default_delete<realm::Replication> >&, std::__1::unique_ptr<realm::SharedGroup, std::__1::default_delete<realm::SharedGroup> >&, std::__1::unique_ptr<realm::Group, std::__1::default_delete<realm::Group> >&, realm::Realm*) + 985600 (memory:3006)
11  Realm                           0x0000000101f944e0 realm::Realm::Realm(realm::Realm::Config, std::__1::shared_ptr<realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator>) + 984288 (shared_realm.cpp:55)
12  Realm                           0x0000000101ed9658 realm::Realm::make_shared_realm(realm::Realm::Config, std::__1::shared_ptr<realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator>)::make_shared_enabler::make_shared_enabler(realm::Realm::Config, std::__1::shared_ptr<realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator>) + 218712 (shared_realm.hpp:304)
13  Realm                           0x0000000101ed94cc std::__1::shared_ptr<realm::Realm::make_shared_realm(realm::Realm::Config, std::__1::shared_ptr<realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator>)::make_shared_enabler> std::__1::shared_ptr<realm::Realm::make_shared_realm(realm::Realm::Config, std::__1::shared_ptr<realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator>)::make_shared_enabler>::make_shared<realm::Realm::Config, std::__1::shared_ptr<realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator> >(realm::Realm::Config&&,    std::__1::shared_ptr<realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator>&&) + 218316 (memory:2172)
14  Realm                           0x0000000101ed56a4 realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator::get_realm(realm::Realm::Config) + 202404 (realm_coordinator.cpp:229)
15  Realm                           0x0000000101f965f0 realm::Realm::get_shared_realm(realm::Realm::Config) + 992752 (shared_realm.cpp:250)
16  Realm                           0x0000000101f7016c +[RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:error:] + 835948 (RLMRealm.mm:400)
17  RealmSwift                      0x00000001023911e4 Realm.init() + 152036 (Realm.swift:0)
18  RealmSwift                      0x0000000102391178 Realm.__allocating_init() + 151928 (Realm.swift:0)
19  SpotMi                          0x0000000100c9be14 globalinit_33_E3853139275E4567E078AE3BFE0165A3_func0 + 32276 (AppDelegate.swift:23)
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182e7ea14 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182e82240 dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$mp + 60
22  SpotMi                          0x0000000100cc2254 FeedVC.viewDidLoad() + 189012 (FeedVC.swift:84)
23  SpotMi                          0x0000000100cc2650 @objc FeedVC.viewDidLoad() + 190032 (FeedVC.swift:0)
24  UIKit                           0x000000018c9e3ae8 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1040
25  UIKit                           0x000000018c9e36c0 -[UIViewController view] + 28
26  UIKit                           0x000000018c9ea28c -[UIWindow    addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 136
27  UIKit                           0x000000018c9e74ec -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 272
28  UIKit                           0x000000018ca563a0 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 48
29  UIKit                           0x000000018cc43d10 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3620
30  UIKit                           0x000000018cc48aa8 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1712
31  UIKit                           0x000000018cee42d4 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 800
32  UIKit                           0x000000018d1bc12c +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 160
33  UIKit                           0x000000018cee3f38 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 252
34  UIKit                           0x000000018cee4798 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 732
35  UIKit                           0x000000018d6697d0 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 260
36  UIKit                           0x000000018d669674 -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 448
37  UIKit                           0x000000018d3d72dc __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 220
38  UIKit                           0x000000018d5703dc _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 112
39  UIKit                           0x000000018d3d718c -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 252
40  UIKit                           0x000000018d1bb78c -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 364
41  UIKit                           0x000000018cc471ec -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 540
42  UIKit                           0x000000018d05cde8 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 364
43  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000185bc61f0 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 364
44  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000185bceaf8 __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 224
45  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182e7ea14 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
46  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182e86200    _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 288
47  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000185bfa7f8 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
48  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000185bfa49c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 404
49  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000185bfaa38 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
50  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001834aa97c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
51  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001834aa8fc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
52  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001834aa184 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204
53  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001834a7d5c __CFRunLoopRun + 1048
54  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001833c7e58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
55  GraphicsServices                0x0000000185274f84 GSEventRunModal + 100
56  UIKit                           0x000000018ca4767c UIApplicationMain + 236
57  SpotMi                          0x0000000100c99b4c main + 23372 (SurpriseCell.swift:26)
58  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000182ee456c start + 4
```

And I am calling this function also in my initialviewcontroller(Feedvc), in the viewDidAppear()

The flow of my program is

1.load feedvc

2. if the user is nil
3. Go to the bootVc(thats called from app delegate)

Again what exactly am i doing wrong?

Also, will just declaring a variable of type realm globally and then initialzing the variable in didFinishLaunching() be a better option?

Thanks!

Comment: You say that you're seeing a crash, but you've provided no details about the nature of the crash. Please share the crash log.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response, i have updated my question

Comment: anything on this?

Comment: Do i initialise realm in `init()` in App delegate, as that isn't giving me any crash. The other option that are discussed in the answer have gotten me a crash. what should i be doing now?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not a good idea to create variables outside the class. Try to create

```
var uiRealm = try! Realm()
```

inside the AppDelegate class. And use `(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).uiRealm` in other classes.

Comment: I thought of it actually, but, I need to call `uiRealm` couple of time through different classes, will it be a good practice to initialise the instance every time? Will this cause a memory issue

Comment: You can use AppDelegate instance. Example: let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate; and use appDelegate.uiRealm.

Comment: Thats what I had implemented after that. Thanks for confirming my doubt. Just one more things, Does there  seem to be any other issue than this global initialisation from the crash logs?

Comment: Hey This is giving me an error. It ran in device from, when i executed it from  Xcode, but when I ran it in beta mode it crashed. It gave me a `found nil` exception on Appdelegate

Comment: I think if you create realm instance in every class, it would be fine. Because, as I know, Realm created its instance once.

Comment: I even tried that! I just gives me a blank screen and doesnt do anything